# Should Picasso retry image loading forever when no internet access

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

So I was looking at an http android app that uses both picasso and okhttp, nevertheless when it comes to offline mode picasso keeps trying to load the image forever, I can see a very aggressive retry policy as it keeps getting me errors on a listener callback:

```
picasso.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
                {
                    Debug.info(this, "On image error " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            })
```

Anyone had some hint, I was looking at the fact that picasso tracks the failure load image, attach itself to a broadcast when there is network should try to retry asking for those images, but that is not what I am seeing here, what I am seeing is that picasso is desperately trying to get those image even when there is no connection.

http://corner.squareup.com/2014/05/picasso-23.html

Comment: i am not sure, but maybe because it's supposed to get the image from the cache (disk) or offline ... so it keep trying. not sure, a wild guess :)

Comment: For images that are cache in disk works great the problem comes for images that are network base

Comment: I observe this incessant retry behavior too even when the response is 404. There should never be a retry on 404.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this write up](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/05/picasso-23.html) if picasso failed to get any image picasso will wait for internet to be available. When it will get internet connection,it will try for failed processes. This process will be continued for failed tasks.